# Second updating page files disappear

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form with uploading multiple files.

When I upload let's say two images and when I click submit, the images are displayed properly, but when I edit some other input and click submit button, the images are gone.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];

}

$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = $id";
$result = $db->query($query);

while($row = $db->fetch_object($result)) {
    $id = $row->id; 
    $title = $row->title;   
    $body = $row->body;
    $status = $row->status;
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
    $title = $_POST['title'];   
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $status = $_POST['status']; 


    //if($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) {    
      if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) { //Edit     

        // delete old image 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM postimage WHERE post_id = $id";
        $select_image = $db->query($query);

        while($row = $db->fetch_object($select_image)) {
            $old = $row->filename;
            unlink('../uploads/' . $old);
        }
        $query = "DELETE FROM postimage WHERE post_id = $id";
        $delete_images = $db->query($query);

        foreach($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
            $filename = rand(100,999)."-".$_FILES['image']['name'][$key];
            $filetmp  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];


            if(move_uploaded_file($filetmp, '../uploads/' . $filename)) {
                $query = "INSERT INTO postimage(post_id, filename) ";
                $query .= "VALUES($id, '$filename')";   
                $insert_images = $db->query($query);
            }

        }       
    } 

    $query = "UPDATE posts SET ";
    $query .= "title = '$title', ";
    $query .= "body = '$body', ";
    $query .= "status = '$status', ";
    $query .= "updated = now() ";
    $query .= "WHERE id = $id ";

    $update_post = $db->query($query);              


    //header("Location: posts.php"); 
}

?>  

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-item">
        <label for="title">Post title</label>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" name="title">
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
        <label for="body">Post body</label>
        <textarea id="editor" name="body" rows="10" cols="30"><?php echo $body; ?></textarea>
    </div>  

    <div class="form-item">
        <label for="image">Image</label>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM postimage WHERE post_id = $id";
        $select_image = $db->query($query);

        while($row = $db->fetch_object($select_image)) {
            $filename = $row->filename;

            echo '<img width="100" height="70" src="../uploads/' . $filename . '">';
        }           


        ?>
        <input type="file" name="image[]" multiple>
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
        <label for="status">Post status</label>
        <select name="status">
            <option value="<?php echo $status; ?>"><?php echo $status; ?></option>
            <?php
            if($status == 'published') {
                echo '<option value="draft">draft</option>';
            } else {
                echo '<option value="published">published</option>'; 
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
        <input type="submit" class="form-submit" name="submit" value="Update post">
    </div>  
</form>
```

When I'm using simple form with uploading a single image and connects with only one table,  I usually fix that problem with this:

```
if(empty($image)) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = $id";
    $result = $db->query($query);

    while($row = $db->fetch_object($result)) {
        $image = $row->image;
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem using multiple upload input?

Comment: Please use answer sections for answer and question sections for questions.

Comment: Hi, Peeha. I've already tried that, but stackoverflow won't let me. I have to wait till tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem.

When using multiple file upload, the if statement has to be changed, so in this case it should be: `if(!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][0]))`

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: change it to

`if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name']))`
because `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` always return path to temp so jou cannot test it for empty

Comment: Hi, Edgars.  I've tried that too, but it didn't work. When I open the edit page the images are there, but the file input is empty and that's why when I update the page again, the images are gone. There must be some solution for this.

Comment: after update your images is gone because this if statement `if($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])` returns true, you need to make that it returns true only if images are selected. try to echo what returns `($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` when you edit but dont select images.

Comment: I've tried that too, but it's the same. I've edited my main post. When I check **print_r ($_FILES['image']['name']);** it displays: **Array ( [0] => )**

Comment: I've just tried. It's absolutely the same result. It needs some different logic. The code is working fine and I don't to change it, but it needs adding some other logic that will work on the update. Like I wrote before, usually I create another if statement with checking if the $image is empty, but in this case it doesn't work. Also I have to mention this problem is only related with the file upload. The other fields with input type text are working fine.

Comment: if you say that `print_r()` for `$_FILES['image']['name']` returns `Array ( [0] => )` then `!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])` must return `false` and if statement must be passed. dont understand why it returns true then.

Comment: `print_r (!empty($_FILES['image']['name']));` returns value 1.  When entering the edit page, I'm getting and printing the uploaded images from the database, but the input shows: Choose files: No file chosen and when I click submit, the database doesn't receive any images and that's why is empty.

Comment: im baffled. ok last of my guessing try - `if( empty($_FILES['image']['name']) === FALSE )`

Comment: I've just tried again and it's the same situation. As far as I know most of the Open Source CMS's uses PHP with Ajax here and somehow it holds the uploaded values on editing the page.

Comment: sorry for vasting your time, but seems i cant find the answer.

Comment: That's ok, Edgars. Thank you for trying. :)

Comment: Hi, Edgars. I've found the problem and now it's fixed! :) I've edited the main post.